# compilation error while trying to write UTF-8 text to a text file

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

In my java source code I wanted to write Non-AscII characters i.e some characters in UTF-8 format to a text file using java :

```
  File f = new File("U.txt");
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
  writer.write("लता"); // hindi text
  writer.close();
```

I am using notepad++ as a text editor and I save the file with encoding `UTF-8`. But when I compile the java file I get an error like :

```
 illegal character: \187
 ∩╗┐import java.io.*;
  ^
```

Where am I making a mistake ? What do i need to do ? This is a compilation error !

Comment: use `FileOutputStream` to pass the endcoding as parameter

Comment: @chaitanya10 there is no line  187 . Program has 14 just lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your editor is putting a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your file (which is unnecessary for UTF-8).  I believe notepad++ has a ["utf-8 without BOM" encoding](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/document-properties/encoding), which you should use instead.

Comment: If it is unnecessary for UTF-8,then why does a text editor like notepad++ put it and gives us two options,with and without

Comment: @Y.E.P - that's a very good question, and i have no idea why notepad++ includes the option _with_ a BOM for utf-8.  possibly they accidentally implemented it that way originally, then realized that it was useless, but didn't want to break current users so added a separate encoding without the BOM.